# Application doesnt get my C2DM message?

Tags: java, php, android, android-c2dm

Here is my C2DMReceiver:

```
public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {
public C2DMReceiver() {
    // Email address currently not used by the C2DM Messaging framework
    super("dummy@gmail.com");
}

@Override
public void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
        throws java.io.IOException {
    // The registrationId should be send to your applicatioin server.
    // We just log it to the LogCat view
    // We will copy it from there
    Log.e("C2DM", "Registration ID arrived: Fantastic!!!");
    Log.e("C2DM", registrationId);
};

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("C2DM", "Message: Fantastic!!!");
    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        System.out.println(extras.get("payload"));
        // Now do something smart based on the information
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.e("C2DM", "Error!");
}

}
```

What it should do is show "Message: Fantastic!!!" in the LogCat but it is no where to be seen. What am I doing wrong? I have the registration ID in my web application (written in PHP) but no luck. I get this back when i execute the request:

```
id=0:1311936686518981%48da2b9fb207fa19
```

Using guide: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of things you need to deal with when using C2DM. I think your code looks okay (even though I haven't test it yet). What about your `AndroidManifest.xml`? I've spent almost two days just to realize that my `AndroidManifest.xml` contains some errors so I couldn't make it work.

Read this [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) thoroughly and I suggest you to install (and learn from the source code, of course) the `ChromeToPhone` app so you know the key to C2DM here.

And don't forget that C2DM only works for Froyo (2.2) and up.

Comment: My Manifest looks like [this](http://qas.im/web/manifest.xml). I have been reading but Im really stumped on the subject. I am right now watching a Youtube presentation on mastering C2dm, we will see where that brings me. I am also debugging on a Nexus S with 2.3.3 :)

Comment: What do you mean with "Email address currently not used by the C2DM Messaging framework"?